# Can non-spiking neurons have a sustained synaptic output current?

Tags: neurophysiology

I'm trying to better understand neural models, specifically non-spiking neurons in invertebrate motor control circuits.  I know that a spiking neuron produces spikes in membrane potential that rapidly go away and exhibit an all-or-none response.  I've also been reading that non-spiking neurons generally exhibit a graded potential.  What I don't know is if that graded potential is sustained, or if it rapidly goes away like in a spiking neuron.  In other words, if the membrane potential rises, is it possible for that membrane potential to stay elevated for long periods of time?  If so, what types of mechanisms might cause that?

Comment: Could you link to where you read that "non-spiking neurons generally exhibit a graded potential" just so we know where you're coming from?

Comment: It's a combination of Wikipedia and a paper on the organism C. Elegans.  It may not be correct (and if not, by all means let me know).  The links:

https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms1304 (figure 4 seems to imply that the neuron AVA has a sustained output and graded response to stimulus)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-spiking_neuron under "animal models" seems to imply that there are graded potentials involved